# Configuring Log 4j for GWT Application in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, log4j

Can someone help me configuring log 4j. I am using eclipse and the application is a gwt app. Whenever, i'm starting web app, it is displaying

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I have placed log4j.propeties file in src of the gwt application. The log4j.propeties file contains:

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to Appender1.
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, Appender1,Appender2

# Appender1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.Appender1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=sample.log


# Appender2 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Can someone help??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really named it
"log4j.propeties" instead of
"log4j.properties", then this may be the reason.

Comment: thanks, i was so busy looking for a solution that i forgot to write the file properly. This was the error !!

Comment: And where did you put the log4j.properties file? I have the same error, but can't figure where to put the file....

Comment: I have miss typed the log4j.properties file name. But the mistake was, that I had the file name start with a space.... Changed it, and now, it works fine! :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure that log4j.properties is found on the classpath of your web app. A typical place for it is WEB-INF/classes. If you put your file under `src`, Eclipse *may* deploy it into `WEB-INF/classes`, but it is worth double checking.

You also need to add logger configuration to determine which packages/classes are to log to which appender. E.g.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN
```

Answer (score 3):

Start tomcat with -Dlog4j.debug=true, and you'll see what log4j is doing during initialization.

Where is your log4j jar located? Under /WEB-INF/lib/, or somewhere in the classpath of the server? The error message refers to a class that belongs to tomcat, not to your project. It could be that tomcat itself is not configured properly with log4j.